# Kotlin Multi-inheritance with condition

Tags: kotlin, oop, inheritance

I have a problem I'm facing while implementing a use case in Kotlin. I would like to have something like multiple inheritance with a condition.

I have a class A() with some properties and acts as superclass. This call A() can have two types which are also classes or interfaces which also has some properties, let's name them F() and V(). Now there are two child classes of A() which are CA() and HA() where they also has some properties. Depends on which type is selected for class A(), either the properties of class F() or class V() are also inherited by creating an CA() or HA() object. The question is, is there a possibilty to have conditional inheritance in Kotlin for the type selected while creating CA() or HA() and than inherit the properites of either F() or V()?

btw: the classes CA() and HA() should later represent Entities/Tables in the database.

Comment: Your question is hard to parse, but the answer to "is there a possibilty to have conditional inheritance" is **no**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is difficult for me to follow (as a visual learner).  Could you draw a class diagram?  Or least use some more meaningful class names like Vehicles, Cars, Bikes, etc, etc to illustrate your question?

I think the feature you want is **Generic Classes**.  If I understand correctly, you'd make `A` a generic class:

`class A<T>(..)`

which you then would type in the child to specify which of `F`/`V` you want it to be:

`class CA(..) : A<F>(..)`

Here is are some articles:

- about Generic Classes: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html
- variance/covariance:
  https://typealias.com/guides/illustrated-guide-covariance-contravariance/